# CMD color problems

Tags: python

I want to make my python cmd output colorful!
I have color-codes like this:
`\033[91m`

Now the output in cmd isn't colorful. I get a "←". How can I change this?
Did anybody have the same problem? :D

## Edit

Is there an alternative to cmd? Is it hard to programm a cmd window in e.g. C#?

Comment: look into the `colorama` library

Comment: https://repl.it/@minion3665/Experiment-with-Colour#main.py

Comment: The Windows terminal doesn't support ANSI escape sequences or color codes.

Comment: @Ironkey I still get this weird arrow 

Comment: @PM77-1    I still get this weird arrow 

Comment: That arrow is the graphic for the ESC \033 character.

Comment: @DanD. Ahh, thanks! Why does it work for others? Do they have a different command line?

Comment: How can I change it?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the code in my link with your own? Would it work there?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah, still not working C: But thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add just two more lines at the beginning of your script.

```
import os
os.system("")
```

Comment: This seems to work, but why??

Answer (score 1):

```
from colorist import Color
from colorist import red
import os
os.system("")
red("Hello World")
print(f"Only {Color.BLUE}this part{Color.OFF} is in colour")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style 
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text') 
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background') 
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text') 
print(Style.RESET_ALL) 
print('back to normal now')
```

To print some more cool text, use the library like this

```
from colorama import init 
from termcolor import colored 
  
init() 
  
print(colored('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red'))
```

This will print green text on red background

If you want to use it with these ANSI color codes, you can try this

```
print("\033[91m {}\033[00m" .format("YOUR TEXT"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get this: ```←[93mWarning: No active frommets remain. Continue?←[0m```

Comment: Oh I just found out it is a kind of compiler thing. I have another way and I am just updating my answer

Comment: Just the same
←[31msome red text
←[42mand with a green background
←[2mand in dim text
←[0m
back to normal now

Comment: Could you add a picture of the output please

Comment: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-b7291e-1601569929.png.html

Comment: Did u try all of the methods including the colorama library?

Comment: from colorama import Fore, Back, Style 
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text') 
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background') 
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text') 
print(Style.RESET_ALL) 
print('back to normal now')


This is my code :D

Comment: Could you try to write this in the IDLE. It may be a problem with the basic(Maybe its not a feature) OS CMD prompt.

Comment: So, in VS Code it works. I think it is a problem with windows cmd :D Thanks for your help

Comment: If this answer worked, do give it an upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

You should use third party "cmds" for example, because they often come with more options. Microsoft also publishes many, check out the MS Store :) I use Fluent Terminal. This is graphically also very appealing